# Android Spotify : Creation of .so file of spotifywrapper using JNI in Android gives Undefined Reference error

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

I am trying to write a wrapper file,in order to use spotify API's in our android application.According to the preceding link : http://datababel.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/spotify-eclipse-and-the-android-ndk-1/

I created libspotify.so.I am trying to create spotifywrapper.so file now.But at the time of creation of this spotify wrapper.so files,I am getting following error.

```
"C:\\android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64\\android-ndk-r9c\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
[armeabi] Install        : libspotify.so => libs/armeabi/libspotify.so
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: spotifywrapper <= run_loop.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: spotifywrapper <= tasks.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: spotifywrapper <= jni_glue.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: spotifywrapper <= logger.cpp
jni/logger.cpp: In function 'void log(char const*, ...)':
jni/logger.cpp:40:90: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'pthread_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat]
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: spotifywrapper <= sound_driver.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libspotifywrapper.so

C:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/spotifywrapper/run_loop.o: in function connection_error(sp_session*, sp_error):jni/run_loop.cpp:103: error: undefined reference to 'sp_error_message'

C:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/spotifywrapper/run_loop.o: in function process_events(std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, sp_session*, sp_track*):jni/run_loop.cpp:127: error: undefined reference to 'sp_session_process_events'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libspotifywrapper.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Are these functions within the sourcetree you are compiling, or in another library that should be referenced?  You may want to use tools like recursive `grep` for the source tree or `objdump` on any existing libraries to figure that out.  Once you know where they are supposed to come from you can look into why they aren't being found, or even tell the build system not to worry about that if you are sure they will be there at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, Spotify has released a brand [new Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/). You should *strongly* consider moving any libspotify projects to the new SDK, as libspotify is now considered deprecated for that platform.